# How to do routing in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I have a problem with routing in CI.

I have a controller with parameters that supports categories and subcategories

```
category$1/subcategory$2
```

I came up with such entries, but they do not quite work.

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'ads/cat/$1';   
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'ads/cat/$1/$2';   
$route['(:any)/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'ads/cat/$1/$2/$3';
```

Everything works until I add pagination - `$3`.

I mean pagination works only for `category/subcategory/10...` but when I turn it on `category/10` it treats the 10 as the second parameter, not pagination ...

How to make it work?

This is the code for my controller:

```
public function cat( $cat_alias, $subcat_alias = null)
    {
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $limit = 10 ;

        if (!empty($subcat_alias)) {
        $start = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
        }
        else 
        {
        $start = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;
        }

        if (isset($_GET['city'])) 
        {
        $city = $_GET['city'];

        }

        $where = array( 'catalogue' => $cat_alias );
        $ad_category = $this->Site_model->get_single( 'categories' , $where );
        $children = $this->Site_model->get_childrens($ad_category->id);

        foreach ($children as $child) 
        {
            $childs[] = $child->id;
        }


        if ( !empty( $ad_category ) )
        {

            if (!empty($subcat_alias)) 
                {

                $where = array( 'catalogue' => $subcat_alias );
                $ad_category2 = $this->Site_model->get_single( 'categories' , $where );

                $data['meta']['title'] = $ad_category2->title;
                $data['meta']['desc'] = $ad_category2->description;

                $where = array('category_id' => $ad_category2->id);

                }

                else
                {

                $where = array( 'category_id' => $childs );
                $data['meta']['title'] = $ad_category->title;
                $data['meta']['desc'] = $ad_category->description;
                }

            $ads = $this->Site_model->get( 'ads' , $where, $limit, $start );
            $data['counter'] = $this->Site_model->get_count( 'ads' , $where);


            if ( !empty( $ads ) )
            {

                foreach ( $ads as $ad )
                {
                    $ad_ids[] = $ad->id;
                }
                $where = array( 'id' => $ad_ids );

            if (!empty($city)) 
                {
                $wher = array( 'slug' => $city );
                $ad_city = $this->Site_model->get_single( 'cities' , $wher );


                $where_filter['city_id'] = $ad_city->id; 
                $data['ads'] = $this->Site_model->filter('ads', $where, $where_filter, $limit, $start);



                }
                else
                {

                $data['ads'] = $this->Site_model->get( 'ads' , $where, $limit, $start );

                }


if (!empty($subcat_alias)) {
        $config['base_url'] = site_url(''.$cat_alias.'/'.$subcat_alias.'');
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
    }
    else
    {
        $config['base_url'] = site_url(''.$cat_alias.'/');
        $config['uri_segment'] = 2;
    }
        $config['total_rows'] = $data['counter'];
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $config['per_page'] = 10;
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination"><ul>';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div>';
        $config['first_link'] = false;
        $config['last_link'] = false;
        $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['prev_link'] = '&larr;';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_link'] = '&rarr;';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] =  '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';


        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        $data['categories'] = $this->Site_model->get_categories();
        $data['current'] = $this->uri->segment(1);
        // $data['meta']['title'] = $ad_category->title;
        // $data['meta']['desc'] = $ad_category->description;
        $this->load->view( 'cat' , $data );

            }
            else
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata( 'alert' , 'Aktualnie brak ogłoszeń w tej kategorii.' );
                 redirect( '/' );
            }

        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata( 'alert' , 'Niepoprawna nazwa kategorii.' );
             redirect( '/' );            
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your controller looks something like this:

```
function cat($category, $subcategory, $pagination){...}
```

You need to change it a bit so it can detect if the second parameter is the pagination like so:

```
function cat($category, $subcategory, $pagination=null)
{
    if($pagination == null && is_numeric($subcategory)) $pagination = $subcategory;
    //your code
}
```

This will work if the `$category & $subcategory` are strings but if they are numbers (ids) than you need a bit more check

Comment: The problem is that I use the pagination library built into Codeigniter and I don't know how to use this condition with $pagination == null

Comment: Please paste your controller to your question, so i can update my answer

Comment: Here is my controller. Sorry for the mess and chaos but I'm just learning.

Comment: @gambi I suspect you mistook this answer for your question, so I have voted to reject your edit to this answer and gone ahead and edited your question for you. Apologies if I have incorrectly interpreted what's happened here.

Comment: You only need to modify the lines `if (!empty($subcat_alias)) ` to `if(!empty($subcat_alias) && !ctype_digit((string)$subcat_alias))`
That again only works if `$cat_alias && $subcat_alias` are strings and not numbers/ids

Comment: @Mikeyhun The given solution works, but there is another problem. If I have a second page and another page for one category, i.e. /category/20, then another page is /category/20/30 and another /category/20/40 is created. And it should be category/30 and category/40, respectively.